camunda 8 self managed, assign user task
I'm running camunda 8 as a self managed platform and started a process with via zeebe client. Now I want to assign the user task with the zeebe client to a user but it doesn't work - the task stays unassigned without error response. Could please help me what I'm doing wrong?
This is how I configured the user task in the modeler.

This is my Rest controller with an endpoint for assignment.
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/demo")
class DemoProcessController {

    @Autowired
    private val zeebeClient: ZeebeClient? = null

    @PostMapping("assignUserTask")
    open fun assignUserTask(): ResponseEntity<String> {

        val event = zeebeClient!!.newUserTaskAssignCommand(2251799813742980)
            .assignee("demo")
            .send()
        return ResponseEntity("[ok]", HttpStatus.OK)
    }
}

I copied the userTaskKey from operate.

Since I can start the process with this client I suppose configuration for the zeebe client is okay. Is there an additional step required before assigning the user task?
Please note: I don't want to use the tasklist UI to assign.
Thank you for checking.

I have to use the zeebe rest API to assign the task as documented here: https://docs.camunda.io/docs/next/apis-tools/zeebe-api-rest/specifications/assign-a-user-task/
Port 8080 didn't work for me and I  changed it to 8088.
